# Javascript parser for matlab files (.mat)

Tags: javascript, matlab

I have not been able to find a javascript parser for matlab files (.mat). Is there such a library which could read .mat files and parse them in javascript objects?

Comment: MAT-Files in the latest version are gzip-compressed HDF5 files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. It is indeed very helpful. If I find an HDF5 javascript parser, I would solve my problem. It seems though that I cannot find an [HDF5 javascript parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32306112/hdf5-javascript-parser).

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use MAT/HDF5 for file exchange? Maybe json or similar is a better choice.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: [jMatFile](https://github.com/fluffynukeit/jMatFile).